# Retrieve position of a View defined by another layout

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, position, android-animation

I have a View in the upper-right corner (or whereever) on my screen. I want to animate this View to a certain position. This position is defined by another xml-layout. How can I determine the coordinates of the View within the other layout, so I can animate it to this position?

Background: Let's say the View shows a calculator placed in the upper-right corner. When the user clicks on this calculator-View, it should be animated to a more present place. After this animation the current fragment gets replaced with the CalculatorFragment which contains exactly the same View (and other Views) plus the calculator-logic. The goal is to animate the calculator to the exact position defined by the xml-layout for CalculatorFragment. This way it is possible to create a "seamless" FragmentTransition.

Another way of asking this question could be "How can I find out the position of a View without displaying it on the screen?"
The most promising approach until now was this (but I only get zeros as coords):

```
View fragmentView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_calculator, null);
View calc = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.includeCalculator);
int[] coords = new int[2];
calc.getLocationInWindow(coords);
pictureframe.setAnimateToX(coords[0]);
pictureframe.setAnimateToY(coords[1]);

Log.v(TAG, "X: " + coords[0] + " Y: " + coords[1]);
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having another XML file for position, you can Write it in an xml file inside anim folder of res folder to whichever position you want to animate the view.

And you can load the animation using-

```
android.view.animation.Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimatio
(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.translate);
```

translate.xml:

```
android:fromXDelta="50%p" 
android:fromYDelta="100%p" 
android:toXDelta="0%p" 
android:toYDelta="0%p" 
android:duration="10" 
android:fillAfter="true" />

</set>
```

You can adjust the X and y positions according to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, but my questions was not how to animate the view, but how to retrieve the position of a view of another layout. You see: If I change this "other layout" (let's say I want the calculator be placed at another position), I don't wanna apapt any animation-parameters. First, because I'd do the same work twice (change the view and then change the animation) and second, because there is not only one calculator, but a few other items with the same behavior. For all of these items I'd have to adapt the animation-parameters.